# The Gerbil's quest

Tags: story, rebus, symbols

The king of the Gerbils has recently been killed by the Gerbil's greatest enemy - the snake. To become the next king our Gerbil, called Beastly (ahem), must find and slay the snake. So Beastly must set out on a journey to find him. Unfortunately he has no idea where the snake's abode is. To help, you will need to know the back story.

When the snake slithered sneakily inside the gerbil's cave, he bit the king injecting him with poisonous venom. But this snake has plundered many gerbil caves and stolen a lot of gold. He modified his fangs to give a clue to any hunters - trying to give the gerbils a false hope as he is confident that no gerbil will solve the clue. Before embarking on his journey, Beastly checked the king's stomach (gross I know) where he was bitten. This is what he saw:

[image]

You realise that the each symbol forms a word. The words form a phrase. Each new colour is a different word. The symbols in black form the important words. The important words can be merged together to form one word which is the snake's abode.

> **What is the phrase? Where does Beastly need to go to find the snake?**

Comment: I felt I had to do a set of puzzles about gerbils :) And I'm back! Sorry to ever have been away...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well no-one got this in 6 months so I'll clear this up:

> Cactus.

Bit dubious but:

> The phrases symbolize See 2 Act On US, us being the snakes. The words in black can be merged to form a word.
> See Act Us.
> See = C
> CACTUS

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> "Look to right below us"
>  Eye symbol = look, Two dots = to, Right arrow = right, Down arrow = under/below, United States Flag = U.S. = us

Comment: Not quite, right track, second and last symbols correct

Comment: and remember the big about the black symbols can be merged to make the snakes abode